# Magento - How to set up properly Cron job on shared hosting

Tags: magento, cron

I'm trying to set up correctly the Cron job for my Magento so i can send the newsletter.

I've seen many guides but any of them worked for me.

Here is my PHP info file: http://sportsdirect.bg/phpinfo.php

For now any Cron job is running for my Magento, i need to set it up!

Can you please give me the command i should place in my cPanel so it will run ot every 5 minutes.

My Magento version is 1.9.0.1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to set up cron for every 5 min

```
*/5 * * * * /home/magento/cron.sh
```

You should replace `/home/magento/cron.sh` with as per your setup.This will work for any version of Magento as cron is not dependent on Magento versions.

Try this for your case

```
*/5 * * * * /public_html/HEREisMYmagento/cron.sh
```

Comment: My path to the main web directory is only: `/public_html/HEREisMYmagento/` So how it must look like ?

Answer (score 0):

First you must find the full path to your cron.sh file
/public_html/HereisMymagento/cron.sh is most likely incorrect.

Usually it's /home/yourusername/public_html/HereisMymagento/cron.sh
yourusername could be the username you use to login with, or it could be a random account ID number.

Here is the cPanel Documentation for adding Cron Jobs
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs

You must specify the full path on the server for the command box

If you want to determine the path to your cron job you can use the phpinfo command.

If you are not good with managing php files, your website hosting provider should be happy to help you setup the cron job. Just let them know which file you want to run.

If they are not as helpful you will have to figure it out yourself.

To find this path you can create a php file named phpinfo.php with the following contents

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Put that file in the same location as cron.sh and browse to it with your browser

http://yoursite.com/phpinfo.php

Scroll down to the bottom and look for _SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]
This will indicate the FULL path to the php file.
Just change the filename to cron.sh and put that in the command box in your cPanel cron.

I would suggest removing the file with phpinfo() from the server after you are done so nobody else can see it.